# Permission overwrite open output file. pandoc.exe: withBinaryFile: permission denied (x) Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1 Execu

Tags: output, knitr, pandoc, execution, permission-denied

Folks, when trying to knit a new version of an open output file (html, pdf, docx, pptx) in R markdown the following error message is triggered:

```
pandoc.exe: x.*: withBinaryFile: permission denied (Permission denied) Error: 
pandoc document conversion failed with error 1 Execution halted
```

I know, you can just close the file and there you go, but in my former R-Studio installation it was just overwriting the open file, which saved me one click when changing some graphics parameter to quickly see how it effects the output.

Any idea how to give Rmd the permission to overwrite an open output file?

(W10 64-bit, R 4.3.1, R-Studio 2023.12.0)